# Close button event of excel sheet using VBA

Tags: vba, excel

Would like to execute few self defined code while closing the Excel sheet's window.

Am using workbook_windowDeactivate for the same. Values in VBA script variables are getting corrupted when the control calls the function. Is this normal behavior of VBA? Is there any way to retail the values in variables till the execution of "workbook_windowDeactivate"?

Comment: what do you mean by corrupted? please post the code of the event handler

Answer (score 0):

If you store the variables in a standard module either as static or as global variables excel will keep track of them UNLESS you have to reset the project. For example in a module I have:

```
Public TimeLastDeactivatedSheet1 As Date

Sub showTime()
MsgBox CStr(TimeLastDeactivatedSheet1)
End Sub
```

In ThisWorkbook code I have:

```
Private Sub Workbook_WindowDeactivate(ByVal Wn As Window)
    TimeLastDeactivatedSheet1 = Now   
End Sub
```

You can test what is being recoreded by running the `showTime() sub`. An alternative place to put the code would be the sheet object depending on how you would like it to work:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Deactivate()
    TimeLastDeactivatedSheet1 = Now
End Sub
```

Of course when you close the workbook the project is reset so if you want to keep the variables after closing you will need to store them e.g. on a worksheet or text file. You could do this using the `Workbook_BeforeClose` event handler.

Edit:

Probably easiest to do an example. Put the code in the top line of a standard module:

```
Public TimeLastDeactivatedSheet1 As Date
```

Put this code in a sheet module:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Deactivate()
    TimeLastDeactivatedSheet1 = Now
End Sub
```

Put this code in the workbook module:

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
    MsgBox ("This message is being sent by Workbook_BeforeClose on data stored by Worksheet_Deactivate. Time = " _
            & TimeLastDeactivatedSheet1)
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_WindowDeactivate(ByVal Wn As Window)
    TimeLastDeactivatedSheet1 = Now
    Call MsgBox("This message is being set by Workbook_WindowDeactivate. Time = " & TimeLastDeactivatedSheet1)
End Sub
```

Save the workbook then in excel click on the sheet that you put the colde into, then click on a different sheet then close the workbook. You should see 2 messages, the first from the before close event displaying the time when you desected the sheet and the nextr triggered by the windows deactivate event.

Comment: Variables got reset when the control reaches Workbook_BeforeClose itself. Had set the break point and verified the same.

Comment: @Raja did you have any luck with the code in the edited answer?

Comment: Issue was with variable scope. Earlier it was public. After changing the scope to global it works fine.